# Schedule action in process builder not working

Tags: process-builder, action, schedule

I have a requirement where I need to send an email to contact 1 hour after the created date but for some reason it is not working.

[image]

[image]

But it works perfectly fine when I try to add it as immediate action.

Comment: Emails aren't send out exactly after one hour but are scheduled, so they may arrive a bit late. Another possibility is that by the send time the fields no longer meet the criteria in which case the email isn't send.

Answer (score 2):

Scheduled actions will appear in `Setup | Flows` in the `Paused Interviews` section at the bottom.

When you start your Process Builder, if the scheduled action is scheduled, you will see an entry for the Process Builder's name in the Paused Interviews along with the timestamp when the scheduled action was initiated (not the expected action time which sadly, is not available in this view)

If the Decision Block's record's data changes such that the Decision Block would no longer be true, the entry in Paused Interviews will be deleted/vanish

Debug log is your friend here as you can see whether multiple Process Builders, triggers, or flows are executing *after* the OP Process Builder executes, perhaps undoing the Decision Block' "true" decision and causing the scheduled action to be cancelled.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I did check the Paused Interviews section and i did not see any actions for the object.

Comment: added an update to my answer

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem. It works best when I create a new record that meets the criteria. I can see scheduled action in pause interviews for the new record. But now the problem is for existing/old records that already meets the criteria. If I make any changes to the existing/old records and the criteria is true, the process does not schedule any action.

Comment: So, you have legacy records that meet the decision criteria already and now you want to send a scheduled email to them?  You should edit your post's title to be something like: "How do I get a scheduled action to fire on legacy records that already meet the decision block criteria?" as the answer to this is very different than my answer. (Plus others have answered this question before)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tick Yes in the Advanced section "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" at the bottom of the Criteria section of the process builder.